# How to launch Kitty "inside" a wsl kali win-kex instance?

Tags: kali-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, remote-desktop, x11vnc, kitty

a newbie here.

I just installed `kitty` on `wsl` `kali-linux`,  I am using `win-kex` to use a GUI. When I launch kitty opens on another window "outside" the winkex instance: like a Windows app. So, how can I make kitty work "inside" the winkex session?

[image: Right, the winkex session. Left, the kitty window on windows.]

The message after call kitty is:

> ignoreboth or ignorespace present in bash HISTCONTROL setting, showing
> running command in window title will not be robust

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here, or even what's happening. I know Kitty as a terminal emulator, so I'm guessing your trying to open a terminal between the host and the emulated Windows environment. I can't tell which direction you're trying to connect, or the nature of your problem. You need to clarify what you expect to happen here. Ideally, if you know what they mean, you should also use more specific terms to explain what's actually happening now, such as those here: https://www.kali.org/docs/wsl/win-kex/.

Comment: Oh, @BryKKan, I'm so sorry. I was trying to use kali on wsl and trying to make it work like a native system (Cant' install kali as native system becasue need windows for engineering tools and have a little storage space). So the "issue " here was that kitty was oppening in other window and not "inside" the win-kex instance. I totaly forgot about the other win-kex modes . Launch a winkex instance on enhanced session mode solved the "issue". Thank you so much. I'll make an edit and add the answer that you gave me.

Comment: Great! You did great with the answer too! Just don't forget to edit a bit of the details from your comment back into the original question. Makes it a little more useful to others coming by later if they don't *have* to read the comments first to understand whether they're having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

On win-kex docummentation [here](https://kali.org/docs/wsl/win-kex.) (thanks to [@BryKKan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/160045/brykkan) on comments) the "problem" is solved launching win-kex enhanced session mode (`--esm`):

> ```
> kex --esm --sound
> ```

After that Kitty and all tools open inside the instance alike the native system.